# Catch a exception in nested .then() block

Tags: javascript, promise

I am having a hard time solving this problem

I have a scenario where I have two functions which return a promise
**method1**
**method2**

My code is like this

```
method1().then((token)=>{
  return method2(token).then(()=>{
   //do something
 })
}).catch(err=>console.error(err));
```

Inside the catch block,  I am only able to catch the exceptions or rejections from `method2`.
Exceptions, rejections thrown in `method1` are going uncaught.

I know I could use individual `.catch` for each method like this

```
method1().then((token)=>{
  method2(token).then(()=>{
   //do something
 }).catch(err=>console.error('err of method2', err)
}).catch(err=>console.error('err of method1', err));
```

But I want to handle the exceptions of both the methods inside one outer `.catch` block.

How can I achieve this?, any help will be appriciated.

Thank you.

Comment: You're wrong, rejections from _both_ methods would reach the catch in your first example.

Comment: "*I am only able to catch the exceptions or rejections from `method2`. Exceptions, rejections thrown in `method1` are going uncaught.*" - no they're not. Please provide a [mcve], especially containing the implementation of `method1`. It sounds like it doesn't actually reject the promise returned from the `method1()` call.

Answer (score -1):

There is a difference between the two examples you provided

In the first one:

```
method1().then((token)=>{
  return method2(token).then(()=>{
   //do something
 })
}).catch(err=>console.error(err));
```

You return the promise, so it will be caught by `catch`

In the second one:

```
method1().then((token)=>{
  method2(token).then(()=>{
   //do something
 }).catch(err=>console.error('err of method2', err)
}).catch(err=>console.error('err of method1', err));
```

Parent `catch` won't trigger, because you didn't return the promise

Comment: Yes, but that's irrelevant. The question is about "*exceptions, rejections thrown in method1*", which the OP claims "*are going uncaught.*" in the first snippet.

Answer (score -1):

Re-formatting your code results in:

```
method1()
    .then((token) => {
        return method2(token)
            .then(() => {
                //do something
            })  <===== missing .catch to process the exceptions of method2 (if any)
    })
    .catch(err=>console.error(err));
```

To catch exceptions from method 1 and method2 in the same catch block, try the following:

```
method1()
    .then(method2)
    .then(()=>{
        // do something
    })
    .catch(err=>console.error(err));
```

This should not only remove the need of an anonymous function where only purpose is to call method2. This should also result in all exceptions being processed in the same catch block, regardless whether it's being thrown in method 1 or method2 or the "do something" part.

Comment: "*missing `.catch` to process the exceptions of `method2`*" is wrong. The promise chain is still `return`ed from the `then` callback, so the `catch` will also handle rejections from `method2(token)` just fine. The two snippets you posted work exactly the same in that regard - the only difference between them is that in the first snippet, the `token` variable is still in scope to `// do something`.